# Selecting an displaying a field in SQL Server that has data with single quotes, through PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, single-quotes

There is a microsoft SQL server that I need to get results from. I have been given a specific query. When I use this query in the HeidiSQL application it works. I can always select and display all 100 rows.

I've tried the exact same query in a PHP script. It manages to select and show some of the rows, but it fails to show everything, even though the script fully runs.

Heavily simplified, the PHP script looks like this:

```
$serverName = "ServerName"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Databasename", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"***");
$MSdb = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

 if ($MSdb) {   
    $query=" SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM Table1 "; 
    $result=sqlsrv_query($MSdb,$query);     
    while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
            $field1=$row['field1'];
            $field2=$row['field2'];
            $field3=$row['field3'];
            ?><br><?=$field1?> , <?=$field2?> , <?=$field3?> <?php
            // process the fields and save them into a mysql database
    }
}
?>END!<?php
```

It seems to fail when the data in the SQL server has a single quote in it.

field3 of row 5 is for example this:

```
aaa ‘bb’ cccc
```

If I modify the query with TOP, OFFSET or FETCH NEXT ROWS , then I'm for example able to select and display the first 4 rows, or row 6 till 10. Everything works, as long as I'm excluding row 5 from the query.

If I only select field1,field2 , then I'm able to get all 100 rows with the PHP script.

So somehow this field with the quotes (and several others like it) stop the execution of the query. If I avoid those fields, everything works fine. The PHP script itself will be executed fully, as it always outputs the 'END!' .

I'm assuming that I have to modify the query so that the quotes can be handled better. However, anything I search for is about escaping quotes for INSERT queries, not SELECT queries. So I'm a bit lost here. What do I need to modify?

Comment: *"process the fields and save them into a mysql database"* I'm sure this is related to your issue. What happens when you remove (comment) the mysql insert part ? Can you display everything?

Comment: When I remove that, nothing changes. Even when all I'm doing there is counting the amount of iterations of the while-loop, the result is the same. It would output the counter variable at the end, indicating that only 4 iterations have been performed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the quote that you are showing it's a unicode format. You have to convert them to a normal single quote or change the charset from the output.
Where `‘` isn't the same as `'`, and can break your code if you don't have the proper charset.

Edit: You can try to use `str_replace()` on field 3 to see if it works before you change the charset.

Comment: This shouldn't break the code execution, nor hide anything. Without proper charset, `‘` will be displayed as something like `â€˜`

Comment: @Cid Don't know about that. Because I had the same problem when the data is coming from a db result set loop, like his.